# add multiple field to jquery ui dialog modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a dialog modal and i want to add to them a select field and a table.

There is a html description to a dialog modal and a select field and a table field

```
<div id="task_properties" style="display:none;">
</div>

<div id="properties-list" class="ui-widget">

        <table id="list_task_properties" class="ui-widget_task ui-widget-content">
        <thead>
            <tr class="ui-widget-header">
                <th>Id</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

  <select class="dropdown-toggle" id="selection" style="display:none;">
 </select>
```

and there is a jquery code where i manage the dialog modal

```
function openTaskPropertiesAssignee(taskId){
$('#task_properties').dialog({
    height: 520,
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    title: taskId,
    draggable:true,
    open: function () {
        $('#selection').css("display","block");
        $('#list_task_properties').css("display","block");
        $(this).html($('#selection'));
        $(this).html($('#list_task_properties'));

    },
    buttons: {
        AddPropertie:{
            'class':"add_propertie_button",
            text: 'add propertie',
            click:function(){

            }
        },
        Ok: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
}); 
$("#selection").change(function(){
    console.log($("#selection :selected").text());
});}
```

But when i run, i have only the last field that i added (table), so i can't see both fields (table and select).

Anyone can tell me where i'm wrong, or take me an example to how add two fields in the jquery Ui dialog form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.html() overwrites div content every time you use the method. so use .append() instead of .html(), Like:

```
$(this).append($('#selection'));
$(this).append($('#list_task_properties'));
```

Or you can also use

```
$(this).html($('#selection'));
$(this).append($('#list_task_properties'));
```

Comment: Yes, exactly this. the problem was that .html() overwrite the content, using .append() allow me to add multiple fields. Thank you @Prk